# Simple Tokenizer using SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, tokenize, lexer

I am trying to implement simple tokenizer. For instance

```
phrase(lexer(L), "read N; SUM := 0; "), write(L).
```

Would return:

```
[key(read),id(N),sep(;),id(SUM),sep(:=), int(0)]
```

This is what i have.

```
lexer([Token | Tail]) -->
    lexem(Token),   //is this way to get tokens?
    lexer(Tail).
lexer([]) -->
    [].

lexem --> ?????
```

I would be grateful for any advice how to develop it to make a working tokenizer.

Comment: I assume by `lex(Tail)` you mean `lexer(Tail)`. And `lexem --> ?????` should be `lexem(Token) --> ?????`. `?????` describes what a token looks like. The input stream to your DCG is going to be your string, one character at a time. So start from there, knowing how you have seen a whole token, character by character.

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake. Unfortunately i cant succesfuly make it working. Could  You please give me a short example, for instance how lexem(Token) --> ????? would generete [sep(;)]?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048653/874024) answer

Comment: ooo thank You. But in ur example u had answer containing numbers. And what if i want to have like [key(write),key(read)] and so on. I just dont know how to have named keyword in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add DCG-rules that describe what a lexem is. For example:

```
lexem(key(K)) -->    % key(K) is a lexem
   key(K).           % if K is a key
lexem(sep(S)) -->    % sep(S) is a lexem
   sep(S).           % if S is a separator

% rules for your keywords here
key(read) -->
   "read".
key(write) -->
   "write".

% rules for your seperators
sep(;) -->
   ";".
sep(:=) -->
   ":=".
```

You also might like to add rules to your lexer for whitespace, e.g.:

```
lexer(Ts) --> 
   whitespace,           % whitespace is ignored
   lexer(Ts).

whitespace -->
   [W],
   {char_type(W,space)}. % space is whitespace
```

With this minimal example you can already query a little bit:

```
   ?- phrase(lexer(L), "read ; write").
L = [key(read),sep(;),key(write)] ? ;
no
```

The identifiers and the number are little bit trickier, as you probably want the longest input match, e.g. `"SUM"` matched as `id('SUM')` instead of `id('S'), id('U'), id('M')`. So it's opportune to write identifier//1 such that it produces the longest match as first solution and to use the cut to not search for further solutions. You can use the built-in predicates atom_chars/2 and number_chars/2 to convert between atoms/strings and numbers/strings. The rest is pretty self-explanatory:

```
lexem(id(IA)) -->
   identifier(I),
   !,                     % longest input match
   {atom_chars(IA,I)}.
lexem(int(NA)) -->
   number(A),
   !,                     % longest input match
   {number_chars(NA,A)}.

identifier([C|Cs]) -->    % identifiers are
   capital(C),            % capital letters
   ident(Cs).             % followed by other cl's

ident([C|Cs]) -->
   capital(C),
   ident(Cs).
ident([]) -->
   [].

capital(C) -->
   [C],                   % capitals are
   {char_type(C,upper)}.  % uppercase letters

number([D|Ds]) -->        % numbers are
   digit(D),              % a digit followed
   digits(Ds).            % by other digits

digits([D|Ds]) -->
   digit(D),
   digits(Ds).
digits([]) -->
   [].

digit(D) -->              % a single digit
   [D],
   {char_type(D,digit)}.
```

Now you can query for your above example:

```
?- phrase(lexer(L), "read N; SUM := 0; ").
L = [key(read), id('N'), sep(;), id('SUM'), sep(:=), int('0'), sep(;)] ;
false.
```

Comment: i tried ur explenation but for given example i am getting only false ;/

Comment: ok it is working now but i have sep((;)) instead of sep(;). Why is that?

Comment: @Dago: Probably you added some extra parantheses by accident. Check the heads of the rules. BTW, I updated my answer to match numbers and identifiers in your above example.

Comment: It is great example! Thank you very much.